# Update XMl based off CSV values using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, loops, for-loop, foreach

I have a CSV file with the values as below:

```
Age , Status

29 ,    0
41 ,    1
44,     1
27,     0
60,     1
```

The XML is as below:

```
<office>
  <staff branch="Torrance" Type="Implementation">
    <employee>
        <Name>Raj Parpani</Name>
        <function>Implementation</function>
        <age>29</age>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <Name>Kevin Woo</Name>
        <function>Consultant</function>
        <age>41</age>
    </employee>
  </staff>
  <staff branch="Irvine" Type="Operations">
   <employee>
    <Name>David Woo</Name>
    <function>Data</function>
    <age>42</age>
   </employee>
   </staff>
 </office>
```

If XML age is equal to the age in CSV, I have to append the status attribute for that age from the csv to the employee. I have tried the code as below:

**ORIGINAL CODE**

```
$csv = Import-Csv 'C:\Users\rparpani\Desktop\test2.csv' | Select-Object "Age","Status"
$xml = New-Object XML
$xml.Load("C:\Users\rparpani\Desktop\test.xml")

$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes("/office/staff/employee")

Foreach($row in $csv)
{
    foreach($node in $nodes)
    {

    if($node.age -eq  $row.age)
    {
    $node.SetAttribute("status", $row.Status);
    }


    }

}
```

Can someone please suggest how to change this to do what I want it to do

---

**MODIFIED CODE**

```
    $csv = Import-Csv 'C:\Users\rparpani\Desktop\test2.csv' | Select-Object "Age","Status"
    $xml = New-Object XML
    $xml.Load("C:\Users\rparpani\Desktop\test.xml")

    $nodes = $xml.SelectNodes("/office/staff/employee")


    foreach($row in $csv) {
      foreach($node in $nodes) {
        if ($node.age -eq $row.age) {
          if ($node.status) {
            $node.status.innerText = $row.Status
          }
          else {
            $status = $xml.CreateNode("element", "status", "")
            $status.InnerText = $row.status
            $node.AppendChild($status)
          }
        }
      }
    }

    $xml.Save("C:\Users\rparpani\Desktop\test.xml")
```

Comment: What if there are two employees with same age? You should be comparing with unique variable instead of age that can be same across multiple people

Comment: If age 49 has status 1 on CSV, and there are two employees on xml with that age, we would append status 1 to that employee

Comment: So all employees with age 41 will have status 1

Comment: yes @Jawad, Everyone with Age 41 will have status 1

Comment: Please do not change the entirety of your question / code. If you need to add something to original post, please add that separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code does what you are looking for.

1. You cannot use `SetAttribute` to create a new element with a value/InnerText. You need to create an element and append it to the node you are on. In your example xml, `staff` has two attributes, `branch` and `Type` that can be updated with `SetAttribute` method.
2. If Status already exists, update it with new value.. otherwise create a new element.

**CSV Content**

```
Age,Status
29,0
41,1
44,1
27,0
60,1
```

**Script to add attribute to Node `Employee**

```
foreach($row in $csv) {
  foreach($node in $nodes) {
    if ($node.age -eq $row.age) {
      if ($row.status -eq "0") {
        $node.SetAttribute("status", "Hired")
      }
      else {
        $node.SetAttribute("status", "Fired")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but it says innertext cannot be found on object:  $node.status.innerText = $row.Status

Comment: Cannot set "status" because only strings can be used as values to set XmlNode properties.

Comment: your algorithm creates a new node. I just want to add the attribute like "<employee Status="0"> where 0 should be not fired and 1 is fired so output will be "<employee Status="Not Fired">

Comment: @RajParpani Added the code up top to show you how to add an atribute using a variable. See if this helps

Comment: when it reads the status 1, it is suppose to set the status in xml as "hired". When it reads the status 0, it is suppose to set the status in xml to "Fired". Would i have to have another if?

Comment: @RajParpani Including status of 0 and 1 to show hired and fired statuses

Comment: something is off logic. 29 is 0 which means Hired but output shows the employee of that age  as "fired"

Comment: @RajParpani you're right.. the If statement where you are checking for 0 should be $row.Status instead of $node.status.